# Android: Help with two linear layout that overlaps each other!

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to have two linear layouts inside a third parent layout. I would like the first linear layout orientation to be horizontal and the second one to be vertical.

I tried to achieve this by the following code. However, the second linear layout do not appear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FFFFFF">
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  >
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
android:layout_width="80px" 
android:layout_height="80px"
android:background="@drawable/projects_badge"
android:layout_margin="10px"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="200px" 
    android:layout_height="81px" 
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15px"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#9CC721"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify **`android:orientation`** attribute inside the Parent Layout as well.

### Tips:

**`dp`** and **`dip`** are more preferrable than px.

### Update:

your parent layout should be like:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

your image view in 2nd sub-layout should be like:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="200px" 
    android:layout_height="81px" 
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15px"
 android:scaleType="center"/>
```

Comment: You dont have to specify android:orientation for a LinearLayout. If nothing is mentioned, it's horizontal by default. (Although it increases the readability of the code if you write it down anyway)

Comment: @alextsc ya thanx for letting me know, i dont know because i am in android since last 1.5 years so. But as his layouts are overlapping, i assumed that he wants to have layout in vertical orientation.

Comment: Yeah that might be true. To be honest I just skipped through the question, and since your answer seems correct didn't go into the details. So i basically just saw "i think you need to specify the orientation" and wanted to clear that you don't have to. :)

Comment: @alextsc yes it is ok, it happen sometimes. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Paresh Mayani. :D:D:D I will be grateful if you can help me solving this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775077/android-how-to-translate-an-imageview-from-its-position-to-the-top-of-the-screen Its more complex :)